# enum class: does not name a value error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I have

```
enum class ErrorLevel
    {
        VERBOSE,
        DEBUG_,
        INFORMATION,
        WARNING,
        ERROR
    };
```

This works:

```
assertDetectionParameters( parameterSet, ErrorLevel::WARNING );
```

This does not:

```
assertDetectionParameters( parameterSet, ErrorLevel::ERROR );
```

> Error 1   error C2589: 'constant' : illegal token on right side of '::'
>   Error 2   error C2059: syntax error : '::'

Resharper says:

> "ErrorLevel does not name a value"

I get this error for certain names in my enum.

Comment: `ERROR` is probably already a preprocessor macro somewhere. Try changing it to something else, e.g. `ERROR_`, in order to test this hypothesis,

Comment: Yes, that is it. Please add an answer. Thx.

Comment: A much better solution is to keep preprocessor macros and other code separate by always using `UPPERCASE_NAMES` for macros and only for macros.

Comment: I think `ERROR` is a perfectly legal name and *must not be defined* by any standard compliant compiler. Don't use rubbish compilers.

Comment: @Walter Is there a reason why you think this is a compiler issue? I just tried the same code in a vanilla vs2013 and ERROR isn't defined by the compiler or standard headers.

Comment: I dont think the error does not pop up with helloworld sample. It depends on the right mix of includes.

Comment: @tmanthey: glad that fixed it - comment now converted to answer below...

Comment: The point of `enum class` is that you can stop using casing to make your enum values distinctive.  Just name it `Error` instead and the odds that a macaroni makes your life miserable are greatly reduced.

Comment: @HansPassant: a bad macaroni can really ruin your day though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ERROR` is probably already a preprocessor macro somewhere. Try changing it to something else, e.g. `ERROR_`, in order to test this hypothesis. Alternatively run your code through the preprocessor to see what substitutions are being made (`gcc -E ...` or whatever the equivalent is in Visual Studio).